# Correct way to call a JQuery UI widget super function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget

In JQuery UI, what is the correct syntax to call a super/base function? In my example below should I be calling the base function using `this._super(param1)` or `this._super('myFunction', param1)`?

```
$.widget( "namespace.Foo", {
    _create: function () {
        // ...
        this._super( "_create" );
    },

    myFunction: function(param1) {
        // ...
    }
});


$.widget( "namespace.Bar", $.namespace.Foo, {
    _create: function () {
        // ...
        this._super( "_create" );
    },

    myFunction: function(param1) {
        // Is this correct?
        this._super('myFunction', param1);
        // or this?
        this._super(param1);

        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed here: https://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_super

> Invokes the method of the same name from the parent widget, with any specified arguments. Essentially `.call()`.
>
> **args** Zero to many arguments to pass to the parent widget's method.

```
_setOption: function( key, value ) {
  if ( key === "title" ) {
    this.element.find( "h3" ).text( value );
  }
  this._super( key, value );
}
```

So it's already invoking `_create` in your first example, so you're now sending "_create" as an argument to `this._create()` and doesn't really do anything.

Digging deeper, we see: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/

> `_super()` and `_superApply()` invoke methods of the same name in the parent widget. Refer to the following example. Like the previous one, this example also overrides the `open()` method to log "open". However, this time `_super()` is run to invoke dialog's `open()` and open the dialog.

```
$.widget( "custom.superDialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    open: function() {
        console.log( "open" );
 
        // Invoke the parent widget's open().
        return this._super();
    }
});
 
$( "<div>" ).superDialog();
```

Your first widget is not mutating, so not sure that you need to call `_super()`. In your mutation, you do not need to send an argument to `_create()`. You can for the the other.

```
$.widget( "namespace.Bar", $.namespace.Foo, {
    _create: function () {
        this._super();
    },
    myFunction: function(param1) {
        this._super(param1);
    }
});
```